# Most Boolean Functions are Complex- Analysis Detail

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, upper-lower-bounds

I'm working through a lower bound argument, to show that most Boolean circuits require exponential circuit size. I've hit a wall trying to fill in the details for a bounding argument and was wondering if anyone would be able to help me fix the issue.

Let $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$. Let $n$ denote the number of inputs for the circuit, and let $G$ be the maximum number of gates allowed in the circuit. Suppose that:
$$G < 2^{n}(1-\epsilon)/n - 2n^{2}.$$

Let $a = (3e)^{2}$, and let $x = a(G + 2n^{2})$. Let $y = a2^{n}(1-\epsilon/2)$. We have the following lemma.

**Lemma:** If $n \geq 2[(1-\epsilon)/\epsilon] \cdot \log_{2}(a(1-\epsilon/2))$, then $x \leq y/\log_{2}(y)$.

**Proof (Attempt):** Denote:
$$
n_{0} = 2[(1-\epsilon)/\epsilon] \cdot \log_{2}(a(1-\epsilon/2)).
$$

We have that:
\begin{align*}
x &= a(G + 2n^{2}) \\
&\leq a2^{n}(1-\epsilon)/n \\
&\leq a2^{n}(1-\epsilon)/n_{0} \\
&\leq a2^{n-1}\epsilon/\log_{2}(a(1-\epsilon/2)).
\end{align*}

While I can get $y$ in the numerator (by bounding $\epsilon < 2(1-\epsilon/2)$), I'm struggling with the denominator. In particular, $\log_{2}(a(1-\epsilon/2))$ almost looks like $\log_{2}(y)$. However, increasing the denominator makes the function smaller.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance to anyone who reads this!